# Elements of minimal length in normal closures of elements in free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be a free group of rank $n$. Let $w\in F_n$ be cyclically reduced.

1. What can be said about the element(s) of minimal length from the $\textit{ncl}(w)$ (normal closure of $w$ in $F_n$)? Under what conditions is it a trivial normal root of $w$ (i.e. is conjugate to $w^{\pm 1}$) ?
2. Let $v, w\in F_n$ be cyclically reduced. What can be said about the element(s) of minimal length in $\textit{ncl}(w)\cap \textit{ncl}(v)$? Under what conditions is it a conjugate of $\[ v, w \]$?

Comment: I think there are no good answers. Sometimes there are no non-trivial normal roots, e.g., when $w$ is a proper power (by Newman's theorem); sometimes such normal roots exist, e.g., 
$[x,y]\in \langle\langle xy^{2013}\rangle\rangle$.  

Comment: thanks Anton. I found this paper, which is very relevant: http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FGMJ%2FGMJ43_01%2FS0017089501010102a.pdf&code=ffbe787e8f22b7c3c3e652438a6bb5dd

Comment: sorry, the link doesn't seem to work. The paper is 

"On a question of Remeslennikov" by James McCool. 
